# What's the proper order for the "Countries to Which You Traveled"? that one has to indicate in the travel history in N-400 form for US Naturalization?

Tags: usa, citizenship, paperwork

What's the proper order for the "Countries to Which You Traveled"? that one has to indicate in the travel history in the [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0))?

I wonder whether the order should be chronological, antichronological, lexicographical, some of  other order or nobody cares. I also wonder whether I should list country A twice if I went to US-> country A -> country B -> country A -> US.

[image]

Comment: Please note that they want "_**Countries** to Which You Traveled_" It's "Countries" (plural) , not "Country".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I wonder whether the order should be chronological, antichronological, lexicographical, some of other order or nobody cares.

As the form states: **Start with your most recent trip and work backwards.**

- which is **antichronological**

They want a unique list of countries visited during that trip:

- country A, country B

Comment: There is one more question you have not answered yet. Should it be A, B or A,, B, A ?

Comment: @scaaahu From the way the heading is written, the list should be unique. Otherwise they would probably have written 'Order of Countries to which you have traveled through'.

Comment: I think you're right. I asked the question for the OP, not myself. I naturalized long time ago. I remember I put in A, B, not A,B,A. I believe what the form is looking for is the time the applicant stayed outside US, not really the order of the countries you traveled.

Comment: Sorry I realized my question was ambiguous: I meant to ask, for a given trip outside the US where I visited more than 1 countries, in which order should I list the country? E.g. if I flew US -> Germany -> France -> US, should I list "Germany, France" or "France, Germany"? From your comments and answers it seems that this order doesn't matter.

Comment: Follow-up question:  [What's the proper order for the countries visited during a single trip outside the US that one has to indicate in the travel history in the N400 form?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24116/164)