# What's the proper order for the countries visited during a single trip outside the US that one has to indicate in the travel history in the N400 form?

Tags: usa, paperwork

One has to indicate in the travel history in the [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/n-400) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0)):

[image]

What's the proper order for the countries visited during single trip outside that one has to indicate in the travel history in N-400 form for US Naturalization? Should the order should be chronological, antichronological, lexicographical, some of other order or nobody cares?

Comment: This may or may not be relevant for you, but if you actually went to Cuba, then prepare for your application to undergo a considerable amount of additional scrutiny.

Comment: @GregHewgill thanks, good point! [Which countries in the travel history in the N-400 Naturalization Form may cause one's application to undergo a considerable amount of additional scrutiny?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/q/24123/164)

Answer (score 1):

The order should be antichronological, *i.e.*, begin your list with the most recent trip, then work backwards towards the earliest trip taken within the 5 year period.

The [USCIS Instructions for Form N-400](https://www.uscis.gov/sites/default/files/document/forms/n-400instr.pdf) state in "Part 9. Time Outside the United States" :

> **Item Number 3.** Provide information for every trip (24 hours or longer) you have taken outside the United States during the last 5 years. Start with your most recent trip and work backwards.

Comment: Thanks, this is for the trip order. I'm asking about the order within a trip. Is it also antichronological? e.g., if I flew US->MEX->Cuba-US (and not US->MEX->US->Cuba-US), shall I list Cuba, MEX or MEX, Cuba?

Comment: Those are the only instructions given. Because each trip has a single "entry page" as you fill out the form — as you show in the question — and that form presents each individual trip with a "departure" and "return" date, I think it makes more sense (and follows the organization of the "entry") to list the countries within each trip in the order you entered them.

Comment: Thanks, the instructions likely refer to the paper form, where one indeed has to decide the order between trips: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ePiGx.png