# Which countries in the travel history in the N-400 Naturalization may cause one's application to undergo a considerable amount of additional scrutiny?

Tags: usa, paperwork

One [has to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFvnp.png) indicate which countries one visited for the past 3 or 5  years in the travel history in the [N-400 Application for Naturalization Form](https://www.uscis.gov/n-400) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200716010951/https://www.uscis.gov/system/files_force/files/form/n-400.pdf?download=0)). Which countries may cause one's application to undergo a considerable amount of additional scrutiny?

Comment: I doubt that this can be answered definitively.

Comment: @phoog thanks, I welcome informal answer eg lawyer experiences or even hearsay. I'd prefer a high recall rather than high precision on that country list. I understand the rest of the application may also matter: I prefer to err on the prudent side.

Comment: At a guess, I’d imagine the list would probably include those countries that currently make a non-visa national ineligible for ESTA:  Iran, Iraq, Syria, Sudan, Yemen, Libya or Somalia. Also Afghanistan, and maybe Cuba. Possibly Russia, if visited recently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a tentative list of such countries from the comment section: Iran, Iraq, Syria, Sudan, Yemen, Libya or Somalia. Maybe Afghanistan, Cuba, and if recent, Russia. I'd add perhaps North Korea too. I'm guessing that one's citizenship and origins, as well as the length of the stays, are likely to impact to what extent visiting these countries matter.

---

Comment:

> At a guess, I’d imagine the list would probably include those countries that currently make a non-visa national ineligible for ESTA: Iran, Iraq, Syria, Sudan, Yemen, Libya or Somalia. Also Afghanistan, and maybe Cuba. Possibly Russia, if visited recently. [Traveller](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/users/16118/traveller).  [May 3 at 6:24](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/24123/which-countries-in-the-travel-history-in-the-n-400-naturalization-may-cause-one#comment39887_24123)